# "server error we're sorry. an error has occurred" when opening a file in document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I am using SharePoint Sever. I am trying to open documents in my document library, but I am getting that error.
Any help please!!

[image]

Comment: You need to add the corresponding part of the ULS logs otherwise we won't be able to tell anything from a generic error message like that. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I open the ULS log but I didn't know how to identify the cause! Could you help me pelase !

Comment: There will be date and time in every line of the log. When an exception occurs, take a the log part with the exact date and time (add a couple seconds of earlier and later log entries as well).

Comment: Thanks, please when I copied the correlation ID and try ti find it in the log file, It doesn't exist  !

Comment: Select "Search all fields" in the UlsViewer. If that doesn't help, try to trace it by time.